# Exclude from list empty value

Tags: wordpress, categories

Hello i create a function to display on list all subcategory of master category of WooCommerce and not display the subcategory that are empty without any products.

I use this code but i continue to display on list also the subcategory empty. Where wrong?

```
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($term_children as $child) :
                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'product_cat' );
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $child, 'product_cat' ) ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php // Skip empty terms
if( $child->count <= 0 ) {
    continue;
} ?>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Move your if statement above the `<li>` line. As it sits, that if statement is doing absolutely nothing.

Comment: Hello this not work..nothing cahage.